# How can I temporarily Highlight a selected row with a cell selection, with locked - protected cells?

Tags: excel, vba

When I select any cell I want to highlight the row but the row likely has locked or protect cells, but I still need to highlight the row. for user preference.  Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853914/vba-highlight-current-row-w-o-deleting-all-cell-colours/43859183#43859183 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929769/how-to-keep-initial-cell-color-while-code-is-hilighting-active-row/18951805#18951805

Answer (score 0):

VBA code will select a protected cell even if protected parameters have been set to prevent a user from doing so.

If you were to add the following line to the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, in a worksheet that has certain cells locked and protected against user selection, the entire row will indeed still highlight:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

You might want to expand on this code to identify your work area and other such things.

If you wanted to allow the user to select locked cells but not actually change any values, then you'd probably want to review the protection parameters.

Comment: thanks this worked and the highlight is grey.  Is there a way to choose a different color?    I was using  Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 27 and receive a runtime error 1004 when sheet is protected.  Or does the excel consider the choice of a color is like trying to edit the protected cell??

Comment: There are ways to change the selection colour, but all have draw backs. If your question is more about cell colouring than it is about cell selection then your best bet would be to go with one of the links that @TimWilliams provided - he uses a neat trick with conditional formatting. You're also likely to get a more useful answer if you could construct a question with more detail about what you're trying to achieve and the code you're using, as answers at the moment have to be quite generic.

Comment: Thank you - I was trying to put in the code but I cannot figure out how to do it in the Add Comment section.  I am very hew at this and I appreciate everyone's patience.